# Android Management API IssueCommand not working

Tags: android, .net, android-management-api

When I issue either the LOCK or REBOOT command in Android Management API neither execute on the device:

```
Command command = new Command();
command.Type = "LOCK";
var operation = svc.Enterprises.Devices.IssueCommand(command, "enterprises/LCxxxxxxxx/devices/3ded38daabec2df8").Execute();

//svc is equal to authenticated  Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.AndroidManagementService;
```

Response:

```
Operation.Metadata
Count = 5
    [0]: {[@type, type.googleapis.com/google.android.devicemanagement.v1.Command]}
    [1]: {[type, LOCK]}
    [2]: {[createTime, 2020-01-15 9:59:15 PM]}
    [3]: {[duration, 600s]}
    [4]: {[userName, enterprises/LCxxxxxx/users/10763xxxxxxxxxxx]}
```

Following this here:  https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/issueCommand#commandtype

Already successfully pushed a policy to the device and can retrieve data and De-Provision it.

Thanks

Comment: Hmmmm, ok, today I came in and both are now working....not sure if that API is ready for prime time.  Seem to be alot of issues with it.  Note: I am also seeing the dual REBOOT of device.

Answer (score 0):

The issueCommand issue is already fixed.